# Is it bad practice to continually create new arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using several arrays as part of serialization. The length of these arrays needs to change as the game progresses. In my `Save` method, I am currently creating a new array by using the following line of code:

`int intArray = new int[specifiedLength];`

Is this considered bad practice? Or can the old arrays be easily cleaned up?

Edit: My 'Save' method is called once every 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Really depends on the size of the arrays and how often you create them.  Should be fine if they are not very big and not allocated very much.  This could be a way to optimize in the future -- I would not worry about it until it was a problem.

Comment: If you no longer have any references to the arrays outside of the Save method, they'll get cleaned up automatically and it probably doesn't matter too much. Hard to say for sure without context, but I doubt you're creating large enough arrays often enough for it to be an issue.

Comment: Creating a new array every minute or two is *definitely* not a problem. (Assuming you're not hanging on to them forever...)

Comment: If you create a new array because you need more (or less) storage space, maybe look into lists, like `List<int>` which can be resized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Garbage collector* (`GC`) will collect garbage (unused memory, arrays included) for you, so if you use small arrays you don't have to do anything. However, if you *frequently* (definetely not once in a minute) allocate many *large* arrays, memory allocation can be *time consumning*. If you are looking for performance you may want to try *pooling* these large arrays, e.g.:

```
// Huge array allocation from pool
int[] array = ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Rent(1_000_000);

try { 
  // Do something with the array      
}
finally {
  // Return array to pool 
  ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Return(array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was sort of aware of the Garbage Collector, but was not sure to the extent it cleaned up after me.  I think my project is small enough that it should not be a concern.  I will look more into the specifics of the garbage collector for future refernce though.